# Downloading an application from PC to PS Vita

Tags: ps-vita

I copied applications from my PS Vita to my PC. I formatted the PS Vita, and when I intended to copy the applications back to my Vita, I could no longer find them anywhere but on my PC.
Prior to formatting, I checked whether I could download them back — they were there, visible as day.
In hindsight, I was able to copy images back, but not apps.

Is there any way I can add the apps back?

Comment: "I could no longer find them elsewhere but from my PC" = "I could no longer find them *on* my PC", I take it?

Comment: No. Whst I intended to say was that I can no longer search for the applications on the Vita, but I still have the file downloads in the PC.

Comment: So, your apps and personal files are on your PC, and not on your PS Vita. You want them back on your PS Vita, but can only transfer the files, not the apps?

Comment: Did you login to the Vita with a different PSN ID after formatting?